# How to insert comma in comma separated file

Tags: php, excel, file, csv

I am creating a comma separated file using a data array in a loop. But the problem is that if any location in the array already has a comma then it does not create a correct comma separated file.

How do I include a string with a comma in comma separated file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put qoutation marks (`"`) around the string. If you also have " in the string, escape those by doubling. Example row:

```
"hello world, I'll call you ""Earth""", 4, 2, "another string"
```

So, if you have a string in the variable $field, normalize the field in this fashion:

```
$field = '"'. str_replace('"', '""', $field) .'"';
```

Answer (score 2):

[`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: +1 Will this work If I want to prompt the user to download file when file is successfully created? I checked above link It has an example that creates a file on harddisk but how to prompt the user to download that file as created. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to quote the field:

```
id,name,position
1,"Maxwell, Sam",CTO
2,Bob,Techie
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what program will be reading the file.

If the parser is written as a state machine, commas should not be handled as delimiters when the string has quotes around it.